# Why doesn't my query match by substring?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to use my own script on my site and as of current I have this:

```
SELECT
recipes.name,
recipes.details,
recipes.img_URL,
ingredients.recipe_ID,
products.name,
count(*),
recipes.added_by,
recipes.id
FROM
recipes
Inner Join ingredients ON recipes.ID = ingredients.recipe_ID
Inner Join products ON ingredients.product_ID = products.ID
WHERE
products.name = $value
GROUP BY
recipes.ID ORDER BY
count(*) DESC
```

But the problem with it is that if I search for a word like "egg" it won't find "eggs", I have tried the LIKE command but that dosnt work eaither.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you just looking for a way to find plurals?

Comment: I sure hope you're escaping that $value with $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value); or you'll suffer SQL-injections

Comment: Yes all my values are escaped lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A wildcard for mysql search is %.

Change your search so that instead of the SQL query being `= $value`, it will be `LIKE $value%` - 
ie, egg%

Comment: SELECT recipes.name, recipes.details, recipes.img_URL, ingredients.recipe_ID, products.name, count(*), recipes.added_by, recipes.id FROM recipes Inner Join ingredients ON recipes.ID = ingredients.recipe_ID Inner Join products ON ingredients.product_ID = products.ID WHERE products.name = '%egg%' OR products.name = '%ham%' GROUP BY recipes.ID ORDER BY count(*) DESC

Comment: That didnt work nor did..
SELECT recipes.name, recipes.details, recipes.img_URL, ingredients.recipe_ID, products.name, count(*), recipes.added_by, recipes.id FROM recipes Inner Join ingredients ON recipes.ID = ingredients.recipe_ID Inner Join products ON ingredients.product_ID = products.ID WHERE products.name = 'egg%' OR products.name = 'ham%' GROUP BY recipes.ID ORDER BY count(*) DESC

Comment: ah i fixed it, needed to change the = to a LIKE